# How to replace hex value in bytes file using python

Tags: python, hex, byte

I have a file inside it with values ​​like this:

55 02 00 00 04 29 00 00 69 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 46 31 35 39 42 37 38 44 41 36 34 35 35 34 36 44 5f 23 23 00 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 38 43 36 30 31 31 35 33 43 44 33 35 44 32 42 33 5f 23 23 00 07 00 00 00 33 30 31 30 35 30

I want it to change to this:

55 02 00 00 05 29 00 00 69 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 46 31 35 39 42 37 38 44 41 36 34 35 35 34 36 44 5f 23 23 00 01 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 38 43 36 30 31 31 35 33 43 44 33 35 44 32 42 33 5f 23 23 00 07 00 00 00 33 30 31 30 35 30

I tried like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import os
ori = input("Enter the hex value to be replaced: ")
mod = input('Enter the hex value you want to replace:')
oriconvert = bytes(ori,'utf-8')
modconvert = bytes(mod,'utf-8')
with open('hero.bytes','rb') as test:
    test = test.read()
    test = test.replace(oriconvert,modconvert)
with open('hero.bytes', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(test)
```

Here is my file structure:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XiZejh0OQtzBoOIVuktuMZ7VKBjoj35/view?usp=share_link
Try it and I hope the answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is `bytes.fromhex`, not `bytes`.

```py
import os
ori = input("Enter the hex value to be replaced: ")
mod = input('Enter the hex value you want to replace:')
oriconvert = bytes.fromhex(ori)
modconvert = bytes.fromhex(mod)
with open('hero.bytes','rb') as test:
    test = test.read()
    test = test.replace(oriconvert,modconvert)
with open('hero.bytes', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(test)
```

Comment: Hi Bro when I enter "04" in the ori variable and "06" in the mod variable it gives this error       TypeError: bytes.fromhex() takes exactly one argument (2 given).    . How to fix this

Comment: @Khánh Đàm, I'm sorry. bytes.fromhex() only need one argument -- the string you want to parse. No need to give encoding. I have fixed the code in my answer. You can read the doc see [bytes.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes%20fromhex#bytes.fromhex)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your help